# how to set same date for all the resources column in resourceDay view using fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I implementing resourceDay view to single day for events using fullcalendar. when i split the resources column,i get different start date and end date but i want to same date all the resources column, i mean one date with different resource,please help me how fix this problem. my code for getting resourceDay view as follows.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
      },
      defaultView: 'resourceDay',
      slotMinutes: 10,
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      editable: true,
      contentHeight: 530,

      resources: <?php echo json_encode($return_resource); ?>,              

      events: <?php echo json_encode($return_arr); ?>,

      select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                $(' #newSession').show();
                $('.calendersize').css({marginLeft : "0px", width: "648px"});

                var currentDate = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-d'));
                var agendaDate = ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'dddd MMM d, yyyy'));

                $(' #agendaDate').text(agendaDate);

                var startTimeSet=($.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-d hh:mm tt'));
                var endTimeSet=( $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'yyyy-MM-d hh:mm tt'));
                ......
              },
```

please help me how to set same date for all the resource column.

Comment: could you post a fiddle or pen...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the event object structure is correct and try this:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay, event, resourceId) {
    alert(resourceId);
}
```